# Tkinter - Image won't show up on button despite keeping global reference

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I want to place a button in the upper right corner and have the button be an image. I understand about scoping/garbage-collection etc. and have seen all the other questions asked here that overlook this fact.

However, I have tried numerous methods including creating a `self.photo` and declaring photo as a global variable. I'm actually not even convinced that that's the issue, because I declare the photo in the same scope as I call the `mainloop()`.

My code right now (which is mostly borrowed from [Drag window when using overrideredirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641616/drag-window-when-using-overrideredirect) since I'm not really familiar with tkinter):

```
import tkinter

pink="#DA02A7"
cyan="#02DAD8"
blue="#028BDA"

class Win(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,master)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self._offsetx = 0
        self._offsety = 0
        self.bind('<Button-1>',self.clickwin)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>',self.dragwin)
        self.geometry("500x500")

    def dragwin(self,event):
        x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self._offsetx
        y = self.winfo_pointery() - self._offsety
        self.geometry('+{x}+{y}'.format(x=x,y=y))

    def clickwin(self,event):
        self._offsetx = event.x
        self._offsety = event.y

win = Win()

# put a close button
close_button = tkinter.Button(win, bd=0, command=win.destroy)
global photo
photo=tkinter.PhotoImage("close.gif")
close_button.config(image=photo, height="10", width="10")

# pack the widgets
close_button.pack(anchor=tkinter.NE)

win.configure(bg=pink)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: `global photo` is useless here btw. `global` is only necessary if you want to write a global variable inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically give `PhotoImage`s a name and use the name in `image` parameters:

```
photo=tkinter.PhotoImage(name='close', file="close.gif")
close_button.config(image='close')
```

I'm not sure if this is the only way, but this works here.

Comment: The name isn't necessary (though there's nothing wrong with using it). The fix is to make sure the path is given to the `file` parameter.

Comment: @BryanOakley RIght, just tried it. Just a habitude of mine doing it with image names.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to create the photoimage is by passing the path to the `file` parameter. Otherwise, your path gets assigned to the internal image name and thus no file will be associated with the image.

```
photo=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="close.gif")
```

Comment: Ug, I had this and it still wasn't working but I had been doing something else wrong and somehow when I changed the other thing I lost the `file=`?? I feel dumb.... XD