# how can i get rid of jumping while moving window on the button?

Tags: python, tkinter

When i try to drag window with buttons, its jumping to the side of window.
here is part of my code:

```
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class WindowDraggable():

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        label.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
        label.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)
        label.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.OnMotion)

    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self,event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x - self.label.winfo_rootx() + self.label.winfo_rootx())
        y = (event.y_root - self.y - self.label.winfo_rooty() + self.label.winfo_rooty())
        root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
```

How can i attach my full code here, because it says that my question is mostly code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YdDP7Qt7

Comment: Stackoverflow is telling you that your question is mostly code because it wants you to explain the problem in detail and create a [mre]. Also the code you have given works properly and smoothly on my computer (Ubuntu). What OS are you using?

Comment: i use windows os

Comment: i mean like, when you drag window with any button cursor is jumping to the body of window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the class:

```py
class WindowDraggable:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window.bind("<Button-1>", self.start_move)
        self.window.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_motion)

    def start_move(self, event):
        self.offsetx = self.window.winfo_pointerx() - self.window.winfo_rootx()
        self.offsety = self.window.winfo_pointery() - self.window.winfo_rooty()

    def on_motion(self,event):
        x = self.window.winfo_pointerx() - self.offsetx
        y = self.window.winfo_pointery() - self.offsety
        self.window.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
```

I store the x and y offsets of the mouse with respect to the window's top left corner. Then I use the offset to calculate the new x and y coords of the window. For more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643532/11106801) (the second piece of code is the one you should look at).